# Prove that there exists a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)$ such that $p_n(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly on every bounded interval [a,b]

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove or disprove the following statement:

(1)Give any continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ (possibly unbounded), there exists a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $p_n(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly on every bounded interval $[a,b]$. (Note: Here the sequence of polynomials should be independent of the interval $[a,b]$.)

(2)There exists a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ that converges to the function $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

In (1) of this question, I think by using Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, we just need to verify that $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ is compacted metric space and the family of all real valued polynomials is an algebra,that contains the constant function and separates points.

In (2), It seems that we just need to use Taylor's expansion.

I don't sure if My thought is right, because my solution seems to be trivial.

Comment: Your outlined argument for (1) will only give you sequence that works for a fixed [a,b]; but it clearly says remember that the sequence is supposed to work for every [a,b], independently of what a and b are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\geqslant 1$, by Stone-Weierestrass there exists a polynomial $p_n$ such that $\|f-p_n\|_{\infty,[-n,n]}\leqslant\frac{1}{2^n}$. I state that the sequence $(p_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ works for $(1)$. Indeed, for any interval $[a,b]$, there is $m\geqslant 1$ such that $[a,b]\subseteq [-m,m]$, therefore for all $n\geqslant m$ we have
$$ \|p_n-f\|_{\infty,[a,b]}\leqslant \|p_n-f\|_{\infty,[-n,n]}\leqslant\frac{1}{2^n} $$
so $(p_n)_{n\geqslant m}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$. As for $(2)$, such a sequence of polynomials cannot exist, otherwise, let $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$, we would have $\|p_n-f\|_{\infty,\mathbb{R}}\leqslant 1$ for all $n\geqslant m$ for some fixed $m$. Therefore
$$ \|p_n-p_m\|_{\infty,\mathbb{R}}\leqslant \|p_n-f\|_{\infty,\mathbb{R}}+\|p_m-f\|_{\infty,\mathbb{R}}\leqslant 2 $$
This means that $p_n-p_m$ is a bounded polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ so it is constant, say $a_n$. Then $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is bounded so it has a subsequence $(a_{\sigma(n)})_{n\geqslant 1}$ converging to some $a\in\mathbb{R}$, therefore $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}p_{\sigma(n)}(x)=p_m(x)+a$ and $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ would be a polynomial which is not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with (2) is the word "uniformly". There is no polynomial $p$ with $|p(x) - f(x)| < 1/2$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.